# How to loop through object to grab object titles

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

My question I think is very simple. How do I loop through an object to then put the object titles into an array. For Example.

```
$randomObject:[
   {
     age: 40,
     eyecolor: blue,
     height: tall
   },
   {
     weight: 140,
     creativity: none,
     playful: sortof
   }

]
```

All of the arrays in the object have different titles in them and I want to be able to take all of the titles and be able to loop through them in an array?

My desired output would be. 
`age, eyecolor, height, weight, creativity, playful`

Comment: what is the desired output of this? And what do you mean by 'title'?

Comment: like the age,eyecolor, height

Comment: The syntax here isn't PHP. Please show your input as a valid data structure literal and your attempt at solving this. Thanks.

Comment: Well im sorry.  I didnt mean to offend you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_keys to extract each array 'title' (key). For example,

```
$array = [
  'key1' => 'something',
  'key2' => 'something2'
];

$all_keys = array_keys($array);
```

For more information about array_keys, check [here](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_keys.php#:~:text=PHP%3A%20array_keys()%20function,-Last%20update%20on&text=The%20array_keys()%20function%20is,the%20keys%20of%20an%20array.&text=Note%3A%20If%20the%20optional%20search_key_value,from%20the%20array%20are%20returned).

Comment: thank you very much for helping me and understanding my question! really means a lot!